# saber cuando scroll llega al final de una modal Angular 4

Tags: html, angular

Estoy haciendo una modal de búsqueda de productos, en la cual tengo un div  llamado ScrollProducts al que le he colocado un overflow-y: scroll, quiero saber cuando el scroll llega al final para ejecutar una función, ose al final del scroll de la modal.

aquí el código

```
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="button_exit">
    <img (click)="closeModal()" data-dismiss="modal" 
      src="/assets/img/icons-25.svg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="oldContent">
   <div class="col oldContentdiv">
    <div class="form" *ngIf="retailer.active_retailer!==null && detalle === false && resumen === false">
      <form (ngSubmit)="goSearch(query)" onsubmit="this.reset()">
        <input id="search-bar" class="search-input" type="text" [(ngModel)]="query" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
          ngModel placeholder="Buscar reemplazo en {{retailer.retailer_active.name}}">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="stocklist.searchQueryDataNewCart === null && !loading" class="carritoVacio">
      <div class="imgCart">
        <img src="assets/img/icons-34.svg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="">
        <div class="title">¿Tu carrito está vacío?</div>
        <div class="descrip">Al parecer no tienes items en tu carrito. Intenta buscar algunos productos para
          poderlos añadir a tu compra.
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="stocklist.searchQueryDataNewCart === null && loading">
      <div class="imgCartGif">
        <img src="assets/img/spinner.gif" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="stocklist.searchQueryDataNewCart !== null && detalle === false && resumen === false" class="conteinerGlobal">
      <div class="headerSearch">
        <div class="busqueda">
          <strong>Palabra buscada: </strong> {{stocklist.searchQueryNewCart | uppercase}}
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="ScrollProducts" >




        <div class="container_Productos" *ngIf="productosCount===false">



          <div class="producto_wrapper animated fadeIn slide" *ngFor="let item of  stocklist.searchQueryDataNewCart; let i = index;"
            style="outline:none;" (mouseover)="mouseOver(item,i)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave(item,i)" [ngClass]="{'borderActive':item.activeButton===true}"
            style="cursor:pointer;">
            <img src="{{item.product.cover[0].original}}" (click)="verProd(i, item)" data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#verProducto" data-backdrop="false">
            <div class="costado" *ngIf="item.activeLike === true" id="{{i}}">
              <div [ngClass]="{'icon heart_off' : item.favoritos===false , 'icon heart_on' : item.favoritos===true}"
                (click)="addFavorites(item,item.favoritos)">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="title" badge-style="badge-assertive" (click)="verProd(i, item)" data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#verProducto" data-backdrop="false">
              {{item.product.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="info" (click)="verProd(i, item)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verProducto"
              data-backdrop="false">
              <span class="price">${{item.price}}</span>
              <div class="unit">{{ util.formatUnitQuantity(item.product.unit, item.product.quantity) }}</div>
              <span class="incart" *ngIf="cartItem.cartitems.count(item) > 0">
                {{cartItem.cartitems.count(item)}}
              </span>
            </div>
            <button *ngIf="item.activeButton === true" id="{{i}}" class="btnCompra" (click)="compraVista(item, cartItem.cartitems.count(item))"
              style="cursor:pointer;">
              Agregar al carrito
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container_Productos" *ngIf="productosCount===true">
          <div class="producto_wrapper animated fadeIn slide" *ngFor="let item of  stocklist.searchQueryDataNewCart; let i = index;"
            style="outline:none;" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave(item,i)" [ngClass]="{'borderActive':item.activeButtonCount===true, 'borderActive':item.activeButtonRemove===true}"
            style="cursor:pointer;">
            <img src="{{item.product.cover[0].original}}">
            <div class="costado" *ngIf="item.activeLike === true" id="{{i}}">
              <div [ngClass]="{'icon heart_off' : item.favoritos===false , 'icon heart_on' : item.favoritos===true}"
                (click)="addFavorites(item,item.favoritos)">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="title" badge-style="badge-assertive">
              {{item.product.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="info">
              <span class="price">${{item.price}}</span>
              <div class="unit">{{ util.formatUnitQuantity(item.product.unit, item.product.quantity) }}</div>
              <span class="incart" *ngIf="item.countOver > 0">
                {{item.countOver}}
              </span>
            </div>

            <div class="acciones_bulk" *ngIf="item.activeButtonCount === true">
              <button class="acciones-button less" (click)="decrement(item,item.countOver)" style="cursor:pointer;">-</button>

              <span class="count">{{item.countOver}}</span>

              <button class="acciones-button more" (click)="increment(item,item.countOver)" style="cursor:pointer;">+</button>
            </div>
            <button *ngIf="item.activeButtonRemove === true" id="{{i}}" class="btnCompraRemove" (click)="removeItem(item)">
              Remover Producto
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-results" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="4" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="500"
          (scrolled)="loadMore()" [scrollWindow]="true" *ngIf="stocklist.scrolledNewCart===true">
          <img src="../assets/img/spinner.gif">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button *ngIf="this.cartItem.cartGet().items.length === 0 && stocklist.searchQueryDataNewCart !== null" class="btn_Naranja blockButton"
      disabled>
      Comprar
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="this.cartItem.cartGet().items.length > 0 && banderaResumen === true" class="btn_Naranja" (click)="gotoPayment()">
      Comprar
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="detalle === true && resumen === false" class="btn_Naranja_detalle" (click)="checkCompra()">
      Comprar
    </button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Como puedo saber cuando el usuario ha llegado al final del scroll de la modal?

Answer (score 0):

En el controlador del Modal, donde tienes el scroll, lo puedes chequear de la siguiente forma:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) === document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // Llego al final y haces lo que necesites aquí dentro
    }
  }
```

> Mas información adicional si deseas leer: [aquí](http://blog.enriqueoriol.com/2018/06/evento-scroll-angular.html)